# Error on converting XML to object using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Packet>
    <Header>
    <Id>1234-1234-1234</Id>
    </Header>
    <Customers>
        <Customer>
            <Name>Try</Name>
            <Age>20</Age>
        </Customer>
    </Customers>
</Packet>
```

And this is how I convert it to object:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xml);
List<Customer> customers = (from customer in xdoc.Element("Customers").Element("Customer")
select new Customer
{
     Name = customer.Element("Name").Value,
     Age = customer.Element("Age").Value
}).ToList();
```

My problem is when I tried to run this code, I got an exception error saying that object reference not set to an instance.

But when i changed my xml to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Customers>
<Customer>
<Name>Try</Name>
<Age>20</Age>
</Customer>
</Customers>
```

It started working and I am getting the name and age. However, the packet and header is one of the requirements on my xml files. How am I gonna do that?

EDIT:
Thanks for all the solutions! They are all working, but may I know what is the best to use (best practices, etc) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query source to:

```
xdoc.Root.Element("Customers").Elements("Customer")
```

`Element` method looks for the element on current level, which is the root for `XDocument`. That's why the query didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Descendants()` method to find elements in xml tree.

```
List<Customer> customers = (from customer in xdoc.Descendants("Customer")
select new Customer
{
     Name = customer.Element("Name").Value,
     Age = customer.Element("Age").Value
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Why is it the least effective @MarcinJuraszek?

Comment: @Gerald, I think  MarcinJuraszek means that this solution is most expensive, bacause the `Descendants()` will traverse all the xml tree. Anyway, this is a good solution if you don't know a structure of the Xml tree.

Comment: Because `Descendants()` traverse whole XML tree looking for elements with given name. Setting the element path manually using `Element(s)` methods lets you save some time from traversing unnecessary parts of the xml tree.

Comment: Ok. I get it now guys. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `LINQ` query to:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xml);
List<Customer> customers = (from customer in xdoc.Element("Packet").Element("Customers").Element("Customer")
select new Customer
{
     Name = customer.Element("Name").Value,
     Age = customer.Element("Age").Value
}).ToList();
```

Because your `Customers` element is located inside your `Packet` element.